# HTA - Not able to set Icon

Tags: hta

I am unable to set icon in HTA application.

```
<HTA:APPLICATION
      SysMenu="no"
      icon="Files\MS.ico"
      VERSION="1.0"/>
```

for above HTA code, Sysmenu completely hide (I mean Icon, Close, Minimize and Maximize)

my requirement is:

1. I want to hide Close, Minimize and Maximize only
2. at the same time HTA icon should be visible.

Comment: You can hide Minimize and Maximize buttons separately, but there's no property for Close button. Setting `SysMenu` to `no` will always hide all the buttons and also the icon, which actually triggers the system menu. [See the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495(v=vs.85).aspx) for further information.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for valuable inputs :)